# Need help finding Vo in this circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

I tried to simplify the circuit as much as possible to find the voltage across the current source. Then, I used voltage division to find my answer. The possible answers are 24, 10, 36 and 12. Where did I go wrong? I got 54V across the 6000 ohm resistor (Vo).

Comment: We should point others to this question when they ask a homework question without showing effort/work. We can say, "Like this. Freshmints did it right."

Comment: Why did you remove the images?

Comment: I came back to this to point someone to a "good" homework question, but lacking the images, it doesn't work. (Removed upvote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your work, you have resistances of 2kohm, 6kohm, and 4kohm on the right branch. Dividing the 72V into *those* results in 36V across the 6kohm resistor.

Or if you do it the current way, you have 6mA through the 6kohm resistor, which requires 36V.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the schematic like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp2pLz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I simplified all of the resistors (as you did) to arrive at 3k total resistance, and get 72 volts total.

Now, with the schematic easier to read, 72 volts across R1 and R2 allows you to figure the current through Node 1:

$$I=V/R$$
$$72V/4k\Omega=18mA$$

And current through Node 2 (R5 and R6 are effectively 4kΩ):

$$72V/12k\Omega=6mA$$

Now we know that R1 and R2 have 18mA while R3 and R4 have 6mA. Since we're only solving for R4 we can ignore R5 and R6.

$$V=IR$$
$$6mA\times6k\Omega=36V$$

For me, rearranging the schematic is helpful.

Comment: Can you recommend some strategy to rearrange the circuit like you did?  I am having trouble visualizing moving the nodes and branches around.  What are my restrictions when moving a node or branch?

Comment: Hm, that's a tough question to answer. I grabbed a sheet of paper and doodled, mentally re-arranging resistors. My goal was to position the current source at left and arrange resistors into branches as they originate from the source. You can move components however you like, but you must keep electrical connections identical. A component pin can be connected to any position on the wire (net) to which it is already connected. By the way, this is a skill you will improve when laying out PCBs. :)